# Preview the photo after selecting the file in Django

Tags: django, imagefield

I can not find information on this topic. How to easily create a 
preview of the photo in Django after selecting it (before saving the form). As on the video below:

[image]

https://youtu.be/HVd2v1aUED0

Is there any simple plugin that will enable this? I think that sending photos in this mode is very popular (that is, a thumbnail of the photo, before saving the whole model).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your django template you can write a small script to display the preview of  the image selected by the user.
In template:

```
<!-- To display image -->
<img id="myimage" src="xyz" > </div>

<!-- To upload new image -->
<input name="images" onchange="readURL(this);" type="file" accept="image/*"/>
```

In the same template:

```js
<script>
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#myimage').attr('src', e.target.result);
        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

</script>
```